# One word or short phrase for ease of visual surveillance if required

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Situation - A person is using a room because it is easier to respond to the sound of a visitor at the gate or door (gate opening, bell ringing, someone calling). It is not necessary that you see the visitor from the room itself. You can step out into a nearby room and look out, largely without being noticed by the visitor.

I came up with ease/facility/facilitation? of visual surveillance (simple)

Or

affordance of spatial layout (technical - architecture background! affordance - 'action possibility')

Any clarification appreciated

Comment: The person is "on the qui vive" (*vigilant, being on alert*).

Comment: He was waiting in that room because it was easy *to see people coming*.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good **sentry station** or **sentry position**.

> A place or position where a person or thing stands or is assigned to stand; a post: a sentry station.

--  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/station

Answer (score 0):

> [***proximity***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proximity) - the state of being near

In this case, *proximity* to the door.